# I don't understand atoi function in K&R C book?

Tags: c, atoi

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char s[]= "9";
    printf("atoi = %d",atoi(s));
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int atoi(char s[])
{
    int i=0,n=0;

    for(i;s[i]>='0' && s[i]<='9';i++)
        n=10*n + (s[i]-'0');
    return n;

}
```

In above program it gave me result `9` as per program it should print ascii value for 9 
and I don't understand what this for loop does.

```
for(i;s[i]>='0' && s[i]<='9';i++)
n = 10*n + (s[i]-'0');
```

Comment: The part `s[i]-'0'` subtracts the character number of whatever number the loop is on from the character number of '0', thus yielding not the ASCII value, but the actual digit.

Comment: It uses the ascii number of the character in the string.
s[0] = '9' = decimal ascii 57.
'0' = decimal ascii 48.
57-48 = 9.

Comment: That isn't what K&R wrote; they would not have written (and _did not write_) the first `i` in `for (i;s[i]>='0' && s[i]<='9';i++)`.  What they wrote (§2.7, p43, of K&R2 with 'Draft Proposed ANSI C' on cover) was: `int i, n; n = 0; for (i = 0; s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9'; ++i)`.  Lots of subtle differences.

Comment: You also shouldn't rely on `system("pause")`, as that is not portable. Instead you should use something like `getchar()` or `fgets()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets break this down:

```
for (i;
```

This creates a for loop, with the loop variable `i`. This is not necessary, but more of a coding style.

```
s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9'
```

This checks to make sure that the character at that index is inside the range for a decimal character (0 - 9), and if it is not, it exits the loop, then returns the number.

```
i++
```

After the loop runs, this increases the index you are checking in the string by one.

```
n = 10 * n
```

This adds an extra digit to 'n' by multiplying by 10, because you know that if you have one more character in your number, it must be multiplied by ten (say I start parsing 100, I read the first two strings, and have 10, there is one more character, so I multiply by ten to get 100.

```
+ (s[i]-'0');
```

This adds the next digit to 'n', the result, which is determined by subtracting the character at the current index by '0', which, when in the range of 0 - 9, returns the integer for that number (if this confuses you, take a look at an [ASCII Chart](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Hopefully this helped you understand.

Comment: If i give string as `s[]="A"` and in for loop `for(i;s[i]>='A' && s[i]<='Z';i++)
  n=10*n + (s[i]-'0');` It should print ascii value for A?

Comment: @ViswanathanIyer No, the function will not, it will return an unexpected value, which would be a mash-up of a lot of numbers. If you want to create a hash from a arbitrary string, there are much better functions out there.

Comment: I want print ASCII value of B using own atoi function how can i implement it in above program?

Comment: What do you mean 'ASCII' value? You can simply write this in your code: `printf("%i", (int) 'B');`, and it will output 66, is that what you want?

Answer (score 3):

this converts string representation to number like "329" to 329
It takes 3 first then 3*10+2=32
then 32*10 + 9 =329

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i;s[i]>='0' && s[i]<='9';i++) /* loop over just the digits, in L->R order */
    n = 10*n + (s[i]-'0');        /* Take value so far, "shift" a 10's place left, 
                                     and add in value of latest digit
                                     (diff between ASCII of digit & ASCII of zero) */
```